# C# Script: I need to add a time delay

Tags: c#

Basically this script will be told to run every 10 min but I only want the script to run during the hours of 9pm - 4am London time can anyone help with this?

Also I would like to limit the script to send no more than 500 e-mails an hour.

```
                  /*Email Client configuration. Here you will need to specify Server, user name and password for your SMTP server, and also testing tag*/
             string SMTPServer = "mail.justshipit.net";
             int SMTPPort = 26;
             string UserName = "no-reply+justshipit.net";
             string Password = "00000";
             string FromEmail = "no-reply@justshipit.net";
             string FromName = "Zoozio @ Amazon";

//email subject and email body
             string Subject = "Please Leave feedback for your [{Source}] order from SUPER COOL STORE";
             string eBayEmailBody = "Hello, [{Name}].\r\n\r\nYou recently purchased:\r\n\r\n[{ItemList}]\r\n\r\nWe hope everything was satisfactory and would really appriciate it if you could go to www.amazon.co.uk/feedback and leave us some positive feedback\r\nif you had any issues please get in contact with us ASAP as we want to sort things out.\r\n\r\nCall Us:0843 289 2766\r\n\r\nMany Thanks\r\nAdam\r\nCustomer Care Manager ";


             /*query syntax. Here we will select all orders processed 14 days ago but not older than 1 month, that don't have FEEDBACK email sent
              and order item table. Two queries in one request
             */
             string query =@"SELECT pkOrderId,cEmailAddress, cFullName, [Source]
FROM [Order] o
LEFT OUTER JOIN Order_LifeHistory ls on ls.fkOrderId = o.pkOrderID and ls.fkOrderHistoryTypeId='EMAIL_SENT'    and ls.Tag='FEEDBACK'
WHERE 
    o.bProcessed = 1 AND o.HoldOrCancel=0 AND o.dProcessedOn > DATEADD(D,-10,GETDATE()) AND ls.sid_history is null 
    AND o.Source IN ('AMAZON');
    SELECT pkOrderId,ItemNumber = oi.ItemNumber,ItemTitle = sis.cItemName
    FROM [Order] o
    INNER JOIN [OrderItem] oi on oi.fkOrderID = o.pkOrderID
    INNER JOIN [StockItems] sis on sis.pkStockID = oi.fkStockID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Order_LifeHistory ls on ls.fkOrderId = o.pkOrderID and     ls.fkOrderHistoryTypeId='EMAIL_SENT'    and ls.Tag='FEEDBACK'
WHERE 
    o.bProcessed = 1 AND o.HoldOrCancel=0 AND o.dProcessedOn > DATEADD(D,-10,GETDATE()) AND ls.sid_history is null 
    AND o.Source IN ('AMAZON');"; 
//SELECT pkOrderId,ItemNumber = oi.ItemNumber,ItemTitle = sis.cItemName
//FROM [Order] o
//INNER JOIN [OrderItem] oi on oi.fkOrderID = o.pkOrderID
//INNER JOIN [StockItems] sis on sis.pkStockID = oi.fkStockID
//LEFT OUTER JOIN Order_LifeHistory ls on ls.fkOrderId = o.pkOrderID and     //ls.fkOrderHistoryTypeId='EMAIL_SENT'    and ls.Tag='FEEDBACK'
//WHERE 
//o.bProcessed = 1 AND o.HoldOrCancel=0 AND o.dProcessedOn > DATEADD(D,-10,GETDATE())     //AND ls.sid_history is null 
//AND o.Source IN ('AMAZON');";
```

Comment: Use the built in [windows task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) for this. No need to build a custom app just to schedule the running of a script.

Comment: I suggest in future when you post questions you consider posting code that doesn't expose your business/customer's internal schemas, infrastructure and identity :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a scheduling framework. `Quartz.net` is a good one for this, and is extremely easy to learn/implement

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a scheduled task/cron job to implement your timer.